# Automorphisms on real numbers

Tags: automorphism-group

I understand that integers are not definable in the real numbers using addition. My problem is that I don't know where it fails.

```
   Question: *Are integers definable in the reals using addition? Justify your answer.*
```

I also understand it should have something to do with an automorphism. I have all the generals without specifics. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you know about: (i) What automorphisms of $(\mathbb{R};+)$ look like? (ii) How automorphisms relate to definable sets?

Comment: It depends. If you assume that constants like $0, 1$ *are* defined (being the neutral elements of addition, multiplication), then integers can be defined as the subset containing them and closed under addition/subtraction.

Comment: To your questions (i) I dont know what they look like. (ii) I know that they map sets to another.

Comment: I should've have been more specific also. My function f ihas be a first order formula.